# Is there a more efficient way to write this simple SQL query?

Tags: sql

Seems like a lot of redundancy here. Is there a more efficient way, or do the unions need to be used? Also the frist `inner join` is there because the `players` table does not have the hotel information and has to be retrieved from `teams`.

```
select players.name
from players
inner join teams
on players.team = teams.name
where teams.staysat = 'Ambassador'
and teams.checkin is not null
and teams.checkin < '18-AUG-07'
and teams.checkout > '18-AUG-07'
--
union all
select officials.name
from officials
where officials.staysat = 'Ambassador'
and officials.checkin is not null
and officials.checkin < '18-AUG-07'
and officials.checkout > '18-AUG-07'
--
union all
select fans.name
from fans
where fans.staysat = 'Ambassador'
and fans.checkin is not null
and fans.checkin < '18-AUG-07'
and fans.checkout > '18-AUG-07';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because you retrieve the data from different tables (players, fans, officials) the union is necessary here, I can only imagine you could shorten this if you would provide a function that pulls the desired information from a table which you would specify as a string, but that would lead to building querys out of strings with concatenation or other headachy stuff so maybe better stick with the union select ;)

Besides, if the tables do not differ in their other columns as well you might consider putting them all into one table and distinguish them over a flag or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right way to do it. The unions and the inner join are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query or view(prefered), like this:

```
select * from (
select players.name as name, teams.checkin as checkin, teams.checkout as checkount, teams.staysat as staysat
from players
inner join teams
on players.team = teams.name

union all
select officials.name as name, officials.checkin as checkin, officials.checkout as checkount, officials.staysat as staysat
from officials

union all

select fans.name as name, fans.checkin as checkin, fans.checkout as checkount, fans.staysat as staysat
from fans

) as t
where t.staysat = 'Ambassador'
and t.checkin is not null
and t.checkin < '18-AUG-07'
and t.checkout > '18-AUG-07';
```

And move outwardly conditions, but it may be more slowly but more simple